# Dockerfile cannot access docker-compose postgresql database url with Prisma

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, nestjs, prisma

I really dont know why but my Dockerfile image cannot access my postgres db running with docker compose. Im using Linux Ubuntu

// prisma.schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

// package.json

```
"scripts": {
"build": "npx nest build",
"format": "prettier --write "src/*/.ts" "test/*/.ts"",
"start": "node dist/main",
"start:dev": "npm run start --watch",
"start:repl": "npm run start --entryFile repl",
"start:debug": "npm run start --watch --debug",
"lint": "eslint "{src,apps,libs,test}/\*/.ts" --fix",
"test": "jest",
"test:watch": "jest --watch",
"test:cov": "jest --coverage",
"test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
"test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
"prepare": "husky install",
"prisma:dev": "npx prisma migrate dev",
"prisma:reset": "npx prisma migrate reset",
"prisma:deploy": "npx prisma migrate deploy",
"prisma:studio": "npx prisma studio",
"docker:up": "docker compose up",
"docker:down": "docker compose down",
"docker:ls": "docker container ls"
},
```

// Dockefile

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package\*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run prisma:deploy
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD \["npm", "run", "start:dev"\]
```

// docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.3-alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: personal
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

// What im running

```
npm run docker:up
```

// Error im having

```
> RUN npm run prisma:deploy:
> personal-info@0.0.1 prisma:deploy
> npx prisma migrate deploy
> Environment variables loaded from .env
> Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
> Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "personal", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"
> Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at localhost:5432
> Please make sure your database server is running at localhost:5432.
```

// .env

```
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@postgres:5432/personal?schema=public"
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@localhost:5432/personal?schema=public"
PORT=8080
HOST="0.0.0.0"
```

**Obs:** if i run docker:up only for postgres with DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@localhost:5432/personal?schema=public" (on localhost) i can access the postgress normally with DBeaver

I tried to run change DATABASE_URL to:
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@postgres:5432/personal?schema=public"
and
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@localhost:5432/personal?schema=public"

Comment: Your statement in the first line is generally true about the Docker image build sequence: a Dockerfile cannot access another Compose service, or otherwise contact another container.  Are you asking [How do I run Prisma migrations in a Dockerized GraphQL + Postgres setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646432/how-do-i-run-prisma-migrations-in-a-dockerized-graphql-postgres-setup)  That question has two approaches for doing it after the image is built.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your Postgres database in a Docker container and then try to access it from another service, like your Node.js application also running in a Docker container, `localhost` will not work as expected.

In the context of Docker, `localhost` refers to the current container. So when your Prisma client tries to connect to `localhost:5432`, it's looking for a PostgreSQL server inside the same container as your Node.js app, which isn't there.

To fix this issue:

1. Use the service name defined in `docker-compose.yml` as the hostname for your database URL
2. Ensure that environment variables are correctly set up for use within your Docker containers

Comment: I've already tried:
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@postgres:5432/personal?schema=public" (postgres:5432 = service name on docker compose)
and
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@localhost:5432/personal?schema=public"  (localhost:5432 = work on DBeaver, but no on Node container)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with this steps: (I'm still accepting other more practical answers to solve this problem)

RUN -> `docker container ls`

COPY: name of the postgres container

RUN -> `docker inspect \ -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' CONTAINER_NAME`

COPY: id of the postgres container

CHANGE:

`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@localhost:5432/personal?schema=public"` **(localhost:5432)**

to

`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@172.19.0.2:5432/personal?schema=public"` **(CONTAINER_IP:5432)**

**Obs:**
I've tried to set DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:pass123@postgres:5432/personal?schema=public" (SERVICE_NAME_ON_DOCKER_COMPOSE:5432) but doens't worked

Answer (score 0):

Another solution i've found too (I'm still accepting other more practical answers to solve this problem):

REMOVE -> DATABASE_URL="xxx" from .env

SET -> DATABASE_URL variable under the docker-compose file

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.3-alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: personal
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:pass123@postgres:5432/personal?schema=public (NOW YOU CAN SET THE NAME OF THE POSTGRES SERVICES AND IT WORKS)
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

**Obs:**
Now the Dockerfile will connect to the docker-compose service, **BUT** you need to run your Dockerfile image under the docker-compose to work, if you run only postgres on docker-compose and run the Dockerfile with docker run IMAGE_NAME wont work